# How do you Reference Images in JS File when using the Asset Pipeline?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, lightbox

I'm using jQuery Lightbox in my Rails 3.1 app.  I'm using the asset pipeline, I'm wondering what's the best way to handle these references to images which are in the .js file:

```
// jQuery Lightbox Init / settings
// Visit http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/ for more options and updates
jQuery("a[href$=.jpg],a[href$=.png],a[href$=.gif]").lightBox({
    imageLoading:   '/images/jquery-lightbox/lightbox-ico-loading.gif', // (string) Path and the name of the loading icon
    imageBtnPrev:   '/images/jquery-lightbox/lightbox-btn-prev.gif',        // (string) Path and the name of the prev button image
    imageBtnNext:   '/images/jquery-lightbox/lightbox-btn-next.gif',        // (string) Path and the name of the next button image
    imageBtnClose:  '/images/jquery-lightbox/lightbox-btn-close.gif',   // (string) Path and the name of the close btn
    imageBlank:     '/images/jquery-lightbox/lightbox-blank.gif'            // (string) Path and the name of a blank image (one pixel)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a js.erb file, you can use ruby and the asset_path methods:

```
   imageLoading: "<%= asset_path 'jquery-lightbox/lightbox-ico-loading.gif' %>"
```

Etc.